# requestAnimationFrame calling at more than 60FPS

Tags: javascript, html, requestanimationframe, game-loop

I'm making a simple game and I'm having a problem where after minimizing the window for a few seconds, upon return the game runs at twice the framerate, and even more after that, adding 60 each time. My game loop looks like this:

```
function disp(){
update();
draw();
requestAnimationFrame(disp);
}
requestAnimationFrame(disp);
```

With both update and draw not including requestAnimationFrame. I have tried this on both firefox and chrome with the same results. Any ideas why this is happening? I've used this same method tons of times and this is the first time this has ever happened.

EDIT: You can find a fiddle of it at http://jsfiddle.net/5ttGs/
It's really simple so far as this kinda paused my progress. Click it a couple times and enjoy 10000+FPS gameplay

Comment: Can you produce a reduced test case on [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) or [jsbin](http://www.jsbin.com) (or a publicly accessible link)?

Comment: Is there an example demonstrating this issue?

Comment: try with a global var animation=requestAnimationFrame(disp) .. the in the loop animation=requestAnimationFrame(disp). this should ensure that you execute it only one time.

Comment: Added it. I looked at my old games and it doesn't have that problem at all.

Comment: You should probably only have `draw` in the `requestAnimationFrame`. update should be in `setTimeout` with some way to deal with changing deltas. Modern browsers tend to limit the rate at which `setTimeout` fires on inactive tabs. `requestAnimationFrame` shouldn't fire at all on inactive tabs.

Comment: you are executing the disp everytime on mouseup.. that creates more request animationframes.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that too late. I was recycling code from something that didn't have a request animation frame. Thanks a lot for the effort guys!

Comment: @Danman what was the solution? Post it as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem with the help of cocco. Basically the `onclick` event called the `disp` function every time the canvas was clicked. Because the `disp` function had a `requestAnimationFrame` frame in it, it called it twice as much every second, resulting in the influx of frames. In order to fix I simply got rid of the disp in
`canvas.addEventListener`

```
function mouse_up() {
var matches = 0;
var overlap = 69;
mouse.up = false;
console.log("clicked", mouse.x,mouse.y);
disp();
}
```

You can find the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/5ttGs/